# Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt, include-path

The error is as above. I have what should be all the necessary files include in the eclipse project:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6
/usr/include
/usr/include/linux
/usr/local/include
```

etc.

I tried `std::cout` and `using namespace std;` `cout` but it still says unresolved.

I have imported `iostream` and `cstdlib`.

Also, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with eclipse 3.7.2.

Code snippet:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "XPLMDisplay.h"
#include "XPLMGraphics.h"

int XPluginStart(char * outName,  char * outSig,  char * outDesc) {
    /* ... */
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    /* ... */
}
```

using namespace std;

---

UPDATE: I had created the eclipse project from existing code. Creating a new c++ project fixes it. I'll accept an answer that explains what setting in the existing project could cause this (so I don't have to cut & paste all my projects).

Comment: Have you imported `iostream`?

Comment: Riight, when we're talking about "importing" iostream, I hope you actually " #include <iostream> " since the notion of importing things is not quite correct in C++.

Comment: @hmjd I can't post all the code, but any more shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Jeff Do you observe this behavior in all your elcipse projects ? Try making something with only the main function and the iostream included and something inserted into cout.

Comment: What is the extension of the source file: `.c` or `.cpp`?

Comment: @hmjd `.cpp` <obligatory length>

Comment: Solved (unsatisfactorily), see latest update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple "could not be resolved" problems using Eclipse with minGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065616/multiple-could-not-be-resolved-problems-using-eclipse-with-mingw)

Comment: @USer22999299 except that my post was submitted almost 2 years before the one you're referencing...

Comment: I didn't wrote it, stack overflow changed my message.. :|

Comment: @USer22999299 fair enough :)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Most likely you have some system-specific include directories missing in your settings which makes it impossible for indexer to correctly parse iostream, thus the errors. Selecting `Index -> Search For Unresolved Includes` in the context menu of the project will give you the list of unresolved includes which you can search in `/usr/include` and add containing directories to `C++ Include Paths and Symbols` in Project Properties.

On my system I had to add `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu` for `bits/c++config.h` to be resolved and a few more directories.

Don't forget to rebuild the index (Index -> Rebuild) after adding include directories.

Comment: perfect solution, kudos.  solved my problem with local error messages regarding mysql methods and classes in c++ on adt+eclipse juno bundle with cdt added (ubuntu 12.04).  upvote, of course!

Comment: for me, Ubuntu 10.04, have to add /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu

Comment: I had to add include_directories("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu") to my cmake file, then the generated eclipse project is able to parse vector, cout, string, and all the other present components from the C++ STL library. For those who need more information about configuring Eclipse CDT projects from CMake files see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453851/how-to-configure-eclipse-cdt-for-cmake

Comment: I just had to rebuild the index, after upgrading my system; the newer eclipse 4.4.1 had had some difficulty while importing workspace / updating plugins etcetera

Comment: For me the following worked:  

**1).** [Select Project Name] --> Index --> Search for Unresolved Includes  

**2).** Clean Project  

**3).** Build Project

Answer (score 24):

To get rid of symbol warnings you don't want, first you should understand how Eclipse CDT normally comes up with unknown symbol warnings in the first place. This is its process, more or less:

1. Eclipse detects the GCC toolchains available on the system
2. Your Eclipse project is configured to use a particular toolchain
3. Eclipse does discovery on the toolchain to find its include paths and built-in defines, i.e. by running it with relevant options and reading the output
4. Eclipse reads the header files from the include paths
5. Eclipse indexes the source code in your project
6. Eclipse shows warnings about unresolved symbols in the editor

It might be better in the long run to fix problems with the earlier steps rather than to override their results by manually adding include directories, symbols, etc.

**Toolchains**

If you have GCC installed, and Eclipse has detected it, it should list that GCC as a toolchain choice that a new C++ project could use, which will also show up in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> New CDT Project Wizard` on the `Preferred Toolchains` tab's `Toolchains` box on the right side. If it's not showing up, see [the CDT FAQ's answer about compilers that need special environments](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_my_compiler.2C_which_requires_special_environment._How_can_I_instruct_Eclipse_to_use_it.3F) (as well as [MinGW](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_MinGW_toolchain_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.) and [Cygwin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I_installed_Cygwin_on_my_PC_but_Eclipse_won.27t_find_it.) answers for the Windows folk.)

If you have an existing Eclipse C++ project, you can change the associated toolchain by opening the project properties, and going to `C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor` and choosing the toolchain you want from the `Current toolchain:` pulldown.  (You'll have to uncheck the `Display compatible toolchains only` box first if the toolchain you want is different enough from the one that was previously set in the project.)

If you added a toolchain to the system after launching Eclipse, you will need to restart it for it to detect the toolchain.

**Discovery**

Then, if the project's `C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Discovery profiles scope` is set to `Per Language`, during the next build the new toolchain associated with the project will be used for auto-discovery of include paths and symbols, and will be used to update the "built-in" paths and symbols that show up in the project's `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` in the `Includes` and `Symbols` tabs.

**Indexing**

Sometimes you need to re-index again after setting the toolchain and doing a build to get the old symbol warnings to go away; right-click on the project folder and go to `Index -> Rebuild` to do it.

(tested with Eclipse 3.7.2 / CDT 8)

Answer (score 16):

Thanks loads for the answers above.  I'm adding an answer for a specific use-case...

On a project with two target architectures each with its own build configuration (the main target is an embedded AVR platform; the second target is my local Linux PC for running unit tests) I found it necessary to set `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer -> Use active build configuration` as well as to add `/usr/include/c++/4.7`, `/usr/include` and `/usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` and then to rebuild the index.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the marked solution here first. It worked but it is kind hacky, and you need to redo it every time you update the gcc. I finally find a better solution by doing the followings:

1. `Project` -> `Properties` -> `C/C++ General` -> `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.`
2. `Providers` -> `CDT GCC built-in compiler settings`
3. Uncheck `Use global provider shared between projects` (you can also modify the global provider if it fits your need)
4. In `Command to get compiler specs`, add `-std=c++11` at the end
5. `Index`->`Rebuild`

Voila, easy and simple. Hopefully this helps.

Note: I am on Kepler. I am not sure if this works on earlier Eclipse.

Comment: This is the solution to a different problem, that of C++11 symbols not being resolved. The OP was having trouble getting even C++98 symbols like `std::cout` resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 / Eclipse 4.2.1 / CDT 8.1.1 and I used to have the same problem for quite some time: importing a C++ project from SVN would cause these annoying "Unresolved inclusion" errors and I would instead have to create a new project and copy the files in there as a work-around (still partial, since SVN functionality would not be there!).

At last, I have just found a simple, satisfactory solution:

- Go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers` and check `Enable language settings providers for this project`.
- Restart Eclipse.

Hopefully that already does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with *std::shared_ptr* with Eclipse using MinGW and gcc 4.8.1. No matter what, Eclipse would not resolve *shared_ptr*. To fix this, I manually added the __cplusplus macro to the C++ symbols and - viola! - Eclipse can find it. Since I specified *-std=c++11* as a compile option, I (ahem) assumed that the Eclipse code analyzer would use that option as well. So, to fix this:

1. Project Context -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols Tab
2. Select C++ in the Languages panel.
3. Add symbol **__cplusplus** with a value of **201103**.

The only problem with this is that gcc will complain that the symbol is already defined(!) but the compile will complete as before.

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to enable the automated discovery in Properties -> C/C++-Build -> Discovery Options to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I simply delete all error in the buttom: problem list.
then close project
and reopen project
clean project
build all
run

then those stupids errors go.

Comment: The question was how to resolve the includes. Not how to delete eclipse warnings.

Comment: Nevertheless this seems to fix the indexer sometimes - at least it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, like it did in my case, then just disable annotations. I started a c++11 project with own makefile but couldn't fix all the problems. Even if you disable annotations, eclipse will still be able to help you do some autocompletion. Most importantly, the debugger still works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using `Eclipse CDT (Kepler)` on `Windows` with `Cygwin` installed. After pointing the project properties at every Cygwin include I could think of, it still couldn't find `cout`.

The final missing piece turned out to be `C:cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.2\install-tool\include`.

To sum up:

- Right click on the project
- Choose `Properties`
- Navigate to `C/C++ General` > `Paths and Symbols` > `Includes` tab
- Click `Add...`
- Click `File system...`
- Browse to the location of your Cygwin `lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.2\install-tool\include`
- Click `OK`

Here is what my project includes ended up looking like when it was all said and done:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You guys are looking under the wrong section.
I realized the difference when I installed in Linux after recently getting frustrated with Windows and the difference was immediately apparent.

In the new setup I have an includes folder in a projected that I created out of existing source.  I can expand this and see a ton of includes; however, I cannot add to them.
This lead me to a hunt for where these files were being listed.

They're listed under the Project Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor Includes > GNU C++
CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [Shared]
Under that is a ton of includes.

These settings are set by the toolchain you've selected.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the Makefile project using cmake on Ubuntu 16.04.

When created the eclipse project for the Makefiles which cmake generated I created the new project like so:

File --> new --> Makefile project with existing code.

Only after couple of times doing that I have noticed that the default setting for the "Toolchain for indexer settings" is none.
In my case I have changed it to Linux GCC and all the errors disappeared.

Hope it helps and let me know if it is not a legit solution.

Cheers,

Guy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen after updating gcc and eclipse on ArchLinux. What solved it for me was `Project -> C/C++ Index -> Rebuild`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding yet another bit of advice after trying a bunch of stuff myself and it not working....

I had GCC installed and the path to the includes set correctly. Had the std error as well, and couldn't get anything working for cout (and I suspect anything in the SL...)

Took me awhile to realize that g++ wasn't installed - gcc was but not g++. So just do:

sudo apt-get install g++

Restart eclipse. Assuming above mentioned details about gcc & paths to includes are fine, you should be okay now...

Answer (score 0):

mine was bit easy to fig out  **right click >run as>run configration**

check boxes **include system lib,inherited mains**