# Eclipse shows errors but project compile fine

Tags: c++, eclipse, syntax-error

I have a c++ project in Eclipse 4.2.1.  It compiles with no errors with external makefile on command line.  However, eclipse shows lots of warnings for functions like "Method 'push_back' could not be resolved" for the vector class.  Any help to get rid of these errors would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have sample code that you can show?

Comment: "warnings" or "errors"?

Comment: Eclipse says they are semantic errors, but there is no actual error since it compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- add the include paths to the eclipse project
- save all files on the project
- close the eproject
- close eclipse
- open eclipse
- open the project

This worked for me with similar issues.

Also check the solutions in:
[Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: In the project properties, under C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols I have /usr/include, /usr/local/include, /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/include, but errors persist. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i actually have them in `Project properties -> c++ general -> preprocessor include paths .. ` be sure to check the c++ thing on the left side.

Comment: OK Thanks a lot.  I found the answer in the link above.