# Eclipse CDT not recognizing <iostream>

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, include-path, eclipse-kepler

Now I know this means I need to add my include path somewhere. So I have gone to properties, C/C++ General, Paths and Symbols, GNU C++ and then I have added /usr/include/c++/4.8 (to debug and release), but intellisense still cant detect  and it the project doesn't build.

Is my include path the correct one for a standard default installation on Linux and did I enter it in the correct Eclipse setting?

This is on Linux Mint 16 and Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that build-essential is installed in your linux

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep build-essential | wc -l
```

if you get 0 as output then install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then install gcc

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```