# Eclipse CDT: nothing could be resolved?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I have a very strange error/bug here:

From one hour to the next, Eclipse isn't able to resolve any of the symbol. E.g.:

*std, list, [own objects]*, or functions like: *size(), append(), cout and so on ...*

I already rebuild and /refreshed the indexer over the whole project and tried to *clean* it too. But without any effort. The only thing new I did was yesterday: I added Doxygen support to my project.

I have no idea where this comes from. I think sending all the source code is *way* too big, it has to be a general Eclips-Error, since I was working like this for weeks.

Eclipse version: `Kepler Service Release 2`

Has anyone an idea?

**UPDATE**

*Thank you for your Support and pardon me I have switched my whole system, thus I can't reproduce your suggestions anymore.*

Comment: WHich verision of Eclipse? Have you tried the latest, Luna?

Comment: added the version. I don't want to switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse CDT: Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: Thank you for your Support. Pardon me I have switched my whole system, thus I can't reproduce your suggestions anymore.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways:

- use system's default lib: when you create the project using "New Project", you can select the "Toolchain for Indexer Setting". For example, I am using Eclipse in Linux so I just choose "Linux GCC". And after the project is created, all the headers will be automatically included for you.
- use you own version of the lib: you need to tell Eclipse the paths to search for the include. Right click the project name, select "C/C++ General" -> "Paths and Symbols" -> "GNU C++". And you can add your paths there.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some system-specific include directories missing in your settings which makes it impossible for indexer to correctly parse iostream, thus the errors. Selecting `Index -> Search For Unresolved Includes` in the context menu of the project will give you the list of unresolved includes which you can search in `/usr/include` and add containing directories to `C++ Include Paths and Symbols` in Project Properties.

On my system I had to add `/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu` for `bits/c++config.h` to be resolved and a few more directories.

Don't forget to rebuild the index (Index -> Rebuild) after adding include directories.