# Eclipse CDT cannot display std::map information

Tags: c++, eclipse, stl, eclipse-cdt

I had a problem when using Eclipse CDT with detecting stl information. I got in-editor errors like "symbol vector could not be resolved". I have solved this using the solution described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13524483/613173

However, it seems that std::map still has problems. For example, the line

```
std::map<int,int> a;
```

Gets the "invalid template arguments" error. Also,

```
a.begin();
```

Gives "method 'begin' could not be resolved" error.

However, with default parameters given explicitly:

```
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > b;
```

I got none of those errors. This **does not** happen with other classes such as std::vector whose template also has more than one argument but I get no complaints over

```
std::vector<int> a;
```

Another problem regards iterators. Even if the map was defined with all parameters given explicitly, the "first" and "second" fields give an error:

```
std::map<int, int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > >::iterator i_b = b.begin();
i_b->first;
```

This gives "Field 'first' could not be resolved".

Compilation works without problems, obviously, but I still want to be able to use Eclipse's static error detection and auto completion.

Eclipse 4.4.2, CDT 8.6.

Comment: Did you `#include <map>`?

Comment: Yes. No effect I can see.

Comment: Are you sure the `<map>` header is in the include path(s) you added? Also, if you started using `std::map` after rebuilding the Index last time, perhaps it's time to rebuild it again.

Comment: What OS are you on? What compiler version? Sometimes these issues are caused by Eclipse not being able to find the right standard library headers.

Comment: This happened to me too.  Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28.0) with CDT 11.2.0.  I do have #include <map> and hitting F3 will open the header file /usr/include/c++/11/map

Comment: @fchen looks like this is Eclipse CDT bug https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/issues/438. This workaround worked for me https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/issues/438#issuecomment-1745775679.